# Netty UnpooledDirectByteBuf

Tags: java, netty

when I read the source code of the UnpooledDirectByteBuf.java of Netty5, I find some code of UnpooledDirectByteBuf.java like this:

```
    public ByteBuf setBytes(int index, ByteBuf src, int srcIndex, int length) {
    checkSrcIndex(index, length, srcIndex, src.capacity());
    if (buffer.hasArray()) {
        src.getBytes(srcIndex, buffer.array(),
                index + buffer.arrayOffset(), length);
    } else if (src.nioBufferCount() > 0) {
                 ... ...
    } else {
        src.getBytes(srcIndex, this, index, length);
    }
    return this;
}
```

I surprise that why we called "`buffer.hasArray()`" here. is `this.buffer` of  UnpooledDirectByteBuf a DirectByteBuffer ? and I think that `buffer.hasArray()` here always return `false`. Am I right? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some left-over from copy and paste. Let me check and remove this in netty :) Thanks!

Comment: Ok fixed: https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/a2ec2a1e3a2b427eaea82743765cb640bfd48935